# How can I use the unique(a, 'rows') from MATLAB in Python?

Tags: python, matlab, numpy

I'm translating some stuff from MATLAB to the Python language.

There's this command, unique(a), in [NumPy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NumPy). But since the MATLAB program runs the 'rows' command also, it gives something a little different.

Is there a similar command in Python or should I make some algorithm that does the same thing?

Comment: have you seen this: http://mail.scipy.org/pipermail/numpy-discussion/2009-August/044664.html

Comment: Ye i saw it, but there's no such command unique1d. I think they removed it at the new Numpy, not sure tho.

Comment: Try `unique` instead of `unique1d` -- the example from that thread should work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming your 2D array is stored in the usual C order (that is, each row is counted as an array or list within the main array; in other words, row-major order), or that you transpose the array beforehand otherwise, you could do something like...

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3], [3, 4, 5]])
>>> a
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [2, 3, 4],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [3, 4, 5]])
>>> np.array([np.array(x) for x in set(tuple(x) for x in a)]) # or "list(x) for x in set[...]"
array([[3, 4, 5],
       [2, 3, 4],
       [1, 2, 3]])
```

Of course, this doesn't really work if you need the unique rows in their original order.

---

By the way, to emulate something like `unique(a, 'columns')`, you'd just transpose the original array, do the step shown above, and then transpose back.

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
ii = 0; wrk_arr = your_arr
idx = numpy.arange(0,len(wrk_arr))
while ii<=len(wrk_arr)-1:
    i_list = numpy.arange(0,len(wrk_arr)
    candidate = numpy.matrix(wrk_arr[ii,:])
    i_dup = numpy.array([0] * len(wrk_arr))
    numpy.all(candidate == wrk_arr,axis=1, iout = idup)
    idup[ii]=0
    i_list = numpy.unique(i_list * (1-idup))
    idx = numpy.unique(idx * (1-idup))
    wrk_arr = wrk_arr[i_list,:]
    ii += 1
```

The results are wrk_arr which is the unique sorted array of your_arr. The relation is:

```
your_arr[idx,:] = wrk_arr
```

It works like MATLAB in the sense that the returned array (wrk_arr) keeps the order of the original array (your_arr). The idx array differs from MATLAB since it contains the indices of first appearance whereas MATLAB returns the LAST appearance.

From my experience it worked as fast as MATLAB on a 10000 X 4 matrix.

And a transpose will do the trick for the column case.