# Extract unique rows from a matrix in numpy with the frequency of each row that was created

Tags: python, matrix, numpy, scipy, unique

A follow up question on:

[How can I use the unique(a, 'rows') from MATLAB in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6776821/how-can-i-use-the-uniquea-rows-from-matlab-at-python)

The answer there explains how to get the unique rows. Yet matlab also returns the frequency of each row that was created. Any elegant way to make it with python?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can count the number of each unique row using fancy indexing and evaluating a condition like:

```
from numpy import unique, array, all
def myunique(input):
    u = array([array(x) for x in set(tuple(x) for x in input)])
    return u, array([len(input[all(input==x, axis=1)]) for x in u],dtype=int)
```

example:

```
a = array([list('1234'),
           list('1234'),
           list('1222'),
           list('1222'),
           list('1234')],dtype=str)

print myunique(a)
#(array([['1', '2', '2', '2'],
#        ['1', '2', '3', '4']],
#       dtype='|S1'), array([2, 3]))
```

Comment: Just thought I'd mention your myunique(x) function explicitly references a... :)

Answer (score 1):

The [numpy_indexed](https://github.com/EelcoHoogendoorn/Numpy_arraysetops_EP) package (disclaimer: I am its author) has a function which does exactly that, in an efficient manner:

```
import numpy_indexed as npi
m = np.random.randint(0, 2, (20, 3))
unique, count = npi.count(m)
```

Answer (score -1):

I came across this issue once.
I did the following: not a perfect solution so much as an elegant hack.

First turn your 2d array into a 1D array or hashable list and from there it is easy. 
One way to transform to a 1D array of floats would be to take dot product with a D-dimensional random vector.
eg:

```
a = np.array([[1.32,1,4],[2,3,3.5],[1.32,1,4],[4,5,6.2]])

b = np.random.randint(1,10**20,3)

c = np.dot(a,b)
vals, idx = np.unique(c,True)
```